# Trying to organize my DIVs

Tags: html, css

I have the following code: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/kwgBP/)

```
<p><strong>One:</strong></p>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix" style="width: 50px; float: left; display: inline-block;">True</div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="float:left; display: inline-block;"><strong>A</strong>: Throughout Windows Azure Connect CTP, many customers have asked for Windows Azure Connect relay presence in geographic locations outside US. Today we are very happy to announce that we have added new relays in Europe and Asia, with the launch of Windows Azure Connect CTP refresh, you can now choose a relay region that is close to your own geographic location to optimize network performance. </div>


</div>     <p><strong>Two:</strong></p>
<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix" style="width: 50px; float: left; display: inline-block;">True</div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="float:left; display: inline-block;"><strong>A</strong>: Throughout Windows Azure Connect CTP, many customers have asked for Windows Azure Connect relay presence in geographic locations outside US. Today we are very happy to announce that we have added new relays in Europe and Asia, with the launch of Windows Azure Connect CTP refresh, you can now choose a relay region that is close to your own geographic location to optimize network performance. </div>
</div>
```

What I am trying to achieve is a heading "One" and below that one row with a DIV on the left containing the word "True" and a div on the right containing text.  Followed by the same thing except with a heading of "Two".

Can anyone out there see what I am doing wrong. The fiddle output looks really bad and totally wrong.

What I want:

```
One
True   dsafjfdsjdsafjdsafasdfasdfasfd
       asdfasdfasdfsdafdsfsdfdsafdsaf
       asfdadsffffffff


Two
False  dsafjfdsjdsafjdsafasdfasdfasfd
       asdfasdfasdfsdafdsfsdfdsafdsaf
       asfdadsffffffff
```

---

After a long time spent looking into this the only thing I could get to work correctly was tables. Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 2):

Is this what you're looking for?  : http://jsfiddle.net/jomanlk/eAFD6/

```
.wrap {
    overflow:auto;
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

h2 {
    display:block;
    background:#AA0000;
}

.state {
    float: left;
    width: 10%;
    background:#00AA00;
}

.text {
    float:right;
    width:80%;
    background:#0000AA;
}

<div class='wrap'>
    <h2>One</h2>
    <div class='state'>True</div>
    <div class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat porttitor commodo. Suspendisse nec diam eros. Donec porta lacus sit amet urna cursus sit amet malesuada mi condimentum. Praesent nec nisi tortor. Nunc accumsan, nulla posuere hendrerit suscipit, arcu enim interdum urna, sit amet suscipit leo ligula vitae eros.</div>
</div>

<div class='wrap'>
    <h2>Two</h2>
    <div class='state'>True</div>
    <div class='text'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam placerat porttitor commodo. Suspendisse nec diam eros. Donec porta lacus sit amet urna cursus sit amet malesuada mi condimentum. Praesent nec nisi tortor. Nunc accumsan, nulla posuere hendrerit suscipit, arcu enim interdum urna, sit amet suscipit leo ligula vitae eros.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this. The only problem is that you specify a width of 10% for the left hand area. What I really need is to have this set to 50px and the let the right area expand or contract horizontally depending on the screen width.

Comment: @DavidH hmmm, off the top of my head, only tables come to mind. Let me experiment and see

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You'll want to remove the borders I put in just to show where the elements are.  The key here was that you need to clear your floats.  Also you need to add a width to the right div containing the text

```
<p><strong>One:</strong></p>

<div class="clearfix">
    <div class="clearfix" style="border: solid; width: 50px; float: left;">True</div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="border: solid; float:left; width: 300px;">
        <strong>A</strong>: Throughout Windows Azure Connect CTP, many customers have asked for Windows Azure Connect relay presence in geographic locations outside US. Today we are very happy to announce that we have added new relays in Europe and Asia, with the launch of Windows Azure Connect CTP refresh, you can now choose a relay region that is close to your own geographic location to optimize network performance.
    </div>
    <div style="clear: both"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I tried this but it has the same problem as the other solution in that you specify a width of 300px for the right hand area. What I really need is to have this set the left width to 50px and the let the right area expand or contract horizontally depending on the screen width.

Comment: Actually if you check out JohnP's answer above you can achieve the effect you're looking for.  I changed the css he had specified on his fiddle example to float the div left and use a width of 90% for the right div and it seems to expand and contract well.
**.text {
    float:left;
    width:90%;
}**

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `style="clear: both;"` on the second div which has the text **Two**

**UPDATE:**

```
<div class="clearfix">
    <p><strong>One:</strong></p>
    <div class="clearfix" style="width: 50px; float: left; display: inline-block;">True</div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="float:left; display: inline-block;"><strong>A</strong>: Throughout Windows Azure Connect CTP, many customers have asked for Windows Azure Connect relay presence in geographic locations outside US. Today we are very happy to announce that we have added new relays in Europe and Asia, with the launch of Windows Azure Connect CTP refresh, you can now choose a relay region that is close to your own geographic location to optimize network performance. </div>   
</div>     
<div class="clearfix" style="clear: both;">
    <p><strong>Two:</strong></p>
    <div class="clearfix" style="width: 50px; float: left; display: inline-block;">True</div>
    <div class="clearfix" style="float:left; display: inline-block;"><strong>A</strong>: Throughout Windows Azure Connect CTP, many customers have asked for Windows Azure Connect relay presence in geographic locations outside US. Today we are very happy to announce that we have added new relays in Europe and Asia, with the launch of Windows Azure Connect CTP refresh, you can now choose a relay region that is close to your own geographic location to optimize network performance. </div>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no second div with th text Two. It's just a paragraph. For some reason seems like I can't clear the first DIV